# Math support for implementation of weighted random sampling

Tags: sampling, simulation, random-generation

I read a paper introducing an implementation of WRS(weighted random sampling) [https://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf](https://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf)
However I was struggling to understand if algorithm A is mathematically equivalent to algorithm D?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What distribution does $u_i=random(0,1)$ indicate?

Comment: u is follow uniform distribution between (0,1)